# Error at line -1 when using SimpleXml to parse xml

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

When parsing my XML files with [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/), I get errors like the following one:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: 
Unable to satisfy ... on field 'id' private String Foo.id 
for class Foo at line -1
```

What do I need to change to get the real line number?

**[EDIT]** Here is a Gist: [Demo for SimpleXml line number problem](https://gist.github.com/1186034)

I'm using simple-xml:2.6.1 and junit:4.9

Comment: Can you show us a sample XML and the code you use?

Comment: Thanks for the Gist. Have you tried expanding the XML string somewhat to include `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and elements?

Comment: The problem isn't in the XML but the default configuration of the XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on where it is run. If you run in JDK 1.5, witout StAX in the classpath this means you are using DOM, so you will always get -1 on an error. If you use JDK 1.5 or above with StAX in the classpath then StAX does not support line numbers (perhaps try a different lib, I recomment [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/)).

**[EDIT]** If you want to try Woodstox and you use Maven, add this to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the version which uses Apache License 2.0. If you prefer LGPL 2.1, replace `-asl` with `-lgpl`.

Comment: Running the Unit Test you wrote in Eclipse and it succeeds. Most probably it's indeed about the missing library. I did add the 3 libraries in lib to the projects build path.